# openerp7.0 In what table of the database is the employee active status

Tags: module, openerp-7

In the Human Resources Module we go >> Employees >> HR Settings Tab >> Active [x] Active

If we uncheck this the Employee is not visible any more in Openerp.

He will not disappear from the DB but will not be visible any more in Openerp.

If we take a look to the hr_employee table the entry is still there.

Witch field is responsible for the active bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

active field is a predefined field in OpenERP. So you don't need to redefined it. you can use it whenever and where ever you want. active field is a special field in class who tell to the view to hide record. If you use filter domain="[('active','=',True)]" this is like you
don't use any filter.you can use else simply  and you will see a
select widget in filter zone of the list.

Comment: is this info stored in the databasee? in witch tableand what is the name of the field?

Comment: yes it stored in database, in which object you declared this active field, for hr_employee a special case, hr.employee class inherits resource.resource object, so this active field for employee aviable in resource_resource table, and it inherit from there